# How to find text with in a webpage?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, richtextbox

I have a textbox and a button,, when I enter a word into the textbox and click the button , its suppose to find the word on the current webpage.

I tried this, sometimes it works and sometimes it dont, I also want to know how to search for the "Next" word in textbox, usually it only searches for the first word typed.

here is my code:

```
dim wb as webbrowser
if wb.documenttext.contains(textbox.text) then
msgbox("YES")
else
msgbox("NO")
```

it does find some words but most of time it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this:

```
If wb.DocumentText.ToLower.Contains(TextBox1.Text.ToLower) Then
    '...
End If
```

Or you could try looping through all the elements, something like this:

```
Private Function HasTextInNode(ByVal elem As HtmlElement, ByVal txt As String) As Integer
    Dim iResult As Integer = 0

    If elem.Children.Count > 0 Then
        For Each child As HtmlElement In elem.Children
            iResult += HasTextInNode(child, txt)
        Next
    ElseIf elem.InnerText <> Nothing AndAlso elem.InnerText.ToLower.Contains(txt.ToLower) Then
        iResult += elem.InnerText.ToLower.Split(txt.ToLower).Length - 1
    End If

    Return iResult
End Function
```

This case, the function return the number of elements in the webpage, but is easy modificable. Hope it helps.